# correctly using va_arg to fetch strings

Tags: c

in `main.c` I call `function(2, "string", "yes")`

where

```
   void function(UINT16 id, const char *ptr_argDescr, ...)
    {
       va_start(argList, ptr_argDescr);

       va_arg(argList, ? );

//and how to copy in array result
```

In `function` I want to get `yes` and then copy it in an array called `result` How should i call va_arg ? Please don't suggest vsprintf. I want to know how I can do it the above mentioned way

Comment: Why is the first argument 2?

Comment: first argument '2' is for other use.. not related to others atall !

Answer (score 3):

"yes" has the type `char*`, and that is the type you should use:

```
char* literal = va_arg(argList, char* );
```

String literals are read only, so if you intend to pass only them, or if you don't intend to modify the array the pointer is pointing to, you could instead use const char*, to so you don't modify them by accident.

Then obtain the length of the string `literal`, allocate storage for a copy `result`, and copy the string.

Comment: To clarify, in C, a string literal has type `char [n]`, where `n` equals number of characters plus 1. For the current context, the type can be decayed to `char *`. In C++, a string literal has type `const char [n]`, which decays to `const char *`.